# syntax error while using YOWSUP

Tags: python, yowsup

i am following this tutorial : http://xebee.xebia.in/index.php/2013/11/25/yowsup-the-whatsapp-api/

in step 3 when i execute this on my terminal :

```
$ python yowsup-cli -c config.example -r sms
```

i get a syntax error saying

```
Detected cc: 20
Failed, reason: old_version. Checking for a new token..
Fetched a new token, persisting !
Now retrying the request..
status: b'fail'
reason: b'old_version'
```

can any body help how can i remove this error

i m a newbie to python

Answer (score 0):

Use the latest yowsup. It is fixed .